# group acting linearly on a topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions

I was wondering what is the meaning of a group acting linearly on a topological space like "circle acting linearly on the $k$-disk $D^k$". I know the meaning of a linear group action on a vector space but for arbitrary topological space, I don't know. Some interesting example will be helpful.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: It just means that for a group $G$ and a topological space $X$ there is a function $G \times X \to X, (g,x) \mapsto g\cdot x$ which acts linearly.  (In essence it is the same as for vector spaces just with some continuity involved.)

Comment: @AlgTop - The question is what does it mean to "act linearly" on an arbitrary topological space which lacks a vector space (or module) structure.

Comment: There is no such meaning. "Linear" is only meaningful when an algebraic structure is involved. Arbitrary topological spaces do not have them. If you look at the context in which the term was used, I'm sure you will find some algebraic structure around. For example, the $k$-disk $D^k$ lives in $\Bbb R^k$, which is a vector space. I'm sure they meant "linearly with respect to the $\Bbb R^k$ vector space structure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural definition is: An action $\times X\to X$ is linear (or, more precisely, is linearizable), if there exists an embedding $f: X\to V$ (where $V$ is a topological vector space) and a continuous linear action $G\times V\to V$ such that
$$
f(gx)= g f(x)
$$
for all $x\in X$. Here it is negotiable what kind of a topological vector space you may want to consider, say, finite dimensional (in which case continuity is automatic) or Banach, or Frechet,... One may also want to impose further restrictions on the (topological) dimension of $X$ and the dimenson of $V$...

In other words, you can think of $X$ as "sitting inside" $V$ such that the action of $G$ on $X$ is the restriction of a (continuous) linear action of $G$ on $V$.